# Copying elements of a slice into a new array

Tags: rust

Is there a nice way of creating an array (that already has elements) and copy the elements of another slice into it?

I thought of maybe sort-of destructuring it?

```rust
fn main() {
    let cmd: u8 = 1;
    let config: &[u8; 2] = &[2, 3];
    let bytes = &[cmd, ..config];
}
```

[Playground (does not work - what I would like to do)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=310d44a99483b7a85ec373acb431ce46)

Basically, is there some syntactical sugar for either:

```rust
fn main() {
    let cmd: u8 = 1;
    let config: &[u8; 2] = &[2, 3];

    let mut bytes: [u8; 3] = [0; 3];
    bytes[0] = cmd;
    bytes[1..].copy_from_slice(config);
    
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f948092dbf188f3a496eb8bf9f7632b)

or

```rust
fn main() {
    let cmd: u8 = 1;
    let config: &[u8; 2] = &[2, 3];
    let bytes = [cmd, config[0], config[1]];
    
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=248ed8f024f3b7aebe80ea23082f1814)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. `copy_from_slice()` is the right way to go.

Comment: It's just very verbose, especially because I find myself doing this a couple of times. I guess I can make a macro for it.

Comment: Ah, no, I can't write a macro since I *technically* don't know the size of the slice... meh.

Comment: @Elias I believe you can on nightly, using `type_alias_impl_trait`, but that involves a lot of work.

Comment: Hm, I'm going to be honest, I'll just stick to `&[cmd, config[0], config[1]];`, since it's mostly just arrays of size 3. I just thought it would be cool if there was a dynamic way to do that, since I have the length of all slices, and would imagine the compiler could figure out a way to do this repetitive work for me.

Comment: @Elias The idea is to emit code [like that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9b14a6774f0ead455d2b621f599561bd), were we use `type_alias_impl_trait` as a poor man's `typeof`. This may be possible only in a proc macro, thought, although I don't believe it (but it will certainly be easier in a proc macro). If only I could find a way to do that on stable...